# OpenOffice Calc Merged Cell properties

Tags: vba, openoffice-calc

I've been searching the web for hours and I can't find an answer for this.  I can identify that a given cell is merged but I need to know how many rows are included in the merged cell.

```
Function aac_MergeRowCount(intStartCol as Integer, intStartRow as Integer)
oSheet = ThisComponent.CurrentController.ActiveSheet
oCell = oSheet.GetCellByPosition(intStartCol, intStartRow)
strData = oCell.GetString()

If oCell.IsMerged Then
    strCopy = strData
    strWasMerged = True
    iCount = oCell.GetNumberOfRows()
End If

aac_MergeRowCount = iCount
End Function
```

Comment: I have tried using getcellrangebyposition but that requires a start row and end row - if I knew the end row I wouldn't need the function.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to ditch OpenOffice and use Excel.  The command I was needing is:

strData = oSheet.Cells(r, c).MergeArea.Rows.Count

Which did not work in OpenOffice